# How do I get size of element in a list that is in a list using stream java

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I am looking for easiest way to amount of item in a list that is in a list, using stream. Here is example:

```
public class ObjectA {
    private List<ObjectB> objectBList;
}

public class ObjectB {
    private List<long> idList;


}
```

I have a list of ObjectA. I want to find how many `ObjectB` I have in the list. This is the simplest form I can come up:

```
long count = 0;
List<ObjectA> objectAList = getListObjectA();
for (ObjectA objectA : objectAList) {
    count += objectA.getObjectBList().size();
}
```

Is there simpler format than this using stream? I will have to go through each element in a list and get the size of second list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there simpler format than this using stream?

Yes, you can use:

```
long count = objectAList.stream()
        .mapToLong(objectA -> objectA.getObjectBList().size())
        .sum();
```

Or also:

```
long count = objectAList.stream()
        .map(ObjectA::getObjectBList)
        .mapToLong(List::size)
        .sum();
```

---

Another smart way as @Holger mentioned, you can use `flatMap` with `count` as this:

```
long count = objectAList.stream()
        .flatMap(objectA -> objectA.getObjectBList().stream())
        .count();
```

Or:

```
long count = objectAList.stream()
        .map(ObjectA::getObjectBList)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .count();
```

Comment: `.count()` is not doing what you want here.

Comment: He is adding the sizes of the lists not counting them.

Comment: @Eritrean I agree, I don't see it correctly, change it!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    System.out.println(list.stream().count());
}
```